# Windows 10 Mobile App background task or service auto start when phone restarts

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, background-task

I am writing a Windows 10 Mobile App (c#); it’s a notification/alarm app; I was wondering can I run a background service or task or scheduler which can trigger alarms or notifications. I am looking for something similar to windows services, so even when my phone restarts, that service or background task starts automatically and continuously run and show notifications to user. I have created windows 10 runtime (background task) but they stop when I restart my phone. How to automatically start a background task or windows mobile service. (It’s a windows 10 mobile app).

Comment: Sorry, don't have the expertise you need, but its likely you meant to tag this question as 'windows 10 mobile' or 'windows phone' rather than windows-mobile. Mobile is their pre 2010 stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have created windows 10 runtime (background task) but they stop when I restart my phone.

Since your background task is for triggering alarms or notifications, theoretically speaking, your background task should not be stopped when you restart your phone. Once the background task is registered, your background task should work until you unregister it or user turn off it, unless there are [resource constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#background-task-resource-constraints) which can force your background task stops.

Based on your description, you can try [Periodic notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-periodic-notification-overview), this notification should also not be effected by restarting of your device.

> How to automatically start a background task or windows mobile service. (It’s a windows 10 mobile app).

I don't know what cause your background task be stopped when your device is restarted, but most of the background tasks can automatically be started by system. By mobile service, I'm not clear what you referred to, if it is the app service like Azure, you can use [Push notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-windows-push-notification-services--wns--overview), if it is the local app service, I personally think this is not quite suitable for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My task is based on DeviceUseTrigger and using  Accelerometer.DeviceId before we can register it. I need to use a Device Trigger for my notifications app; at the moment, I have to manually register the BG Task by pressing a button on my app. I want to read sensor data and want to run my background task automatically even when user restarts the phone.  I can place a tile in start menu for this app so that when the phone starts up the title can start the background process? Is it possible?

Comment: @JAWWAD, "I want to read sensor data and want to run my background task automatically even when user restarts the phone." This should work, did you check your code, is it possible that you unregister the task somewhere?  " can place a tile in start menu for this app so that when the phone starts up the title can start the background process? Is it possible?" To be honestly, I;m not sure since I didn't try it once, but it is possible to start a background task on toast...